# Can an attacker insert malicious code in html5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

So I learned earlier that using the data attribute in html5 you could insert values to be handled in a javascript file. e.g

```
<a href="#" data-name="hello" class="check">Hey</a>
```

the handling javascript file will have a line to handle that link tag which might do this

```
var value=$('.check').data('name');
window.location.href="http://www.example.com/'+value+'";
```

Now I was wondering, can a malicious coder exploit this? Do you need to sanitize the value before using it for a redirect?

Comment: Not anymore than someone could exploit any other piece of HTML on a website, so there's nothing to worry about, at least not any more than usual. And you can't really sanitize clientside code, you only do that if it's sent to the serverside.

Comment: Is this data attribute being created from user input?

Comment: You shouldn't allow un-whitelisted HTML input into your site. Even if you don't have data- attributes. Data attributes are bad for a whole other reason.

Comment: @Blender No. It's given to the user as part of a script tag code. They could always try to modify it, but if they modify the data-name to say data-check, there won't be anything handling it on the javascript side.

Comment: @MichaelNana: So what is being generated with user input?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: What's wrong with `data-` attributes?

Comment: @Blender They completely break separation of concerns by adding application logical data to the DOM instead of storing it in JavaScript objects. The DOM should not be the source of truth in an application, there should be a single source of truth. Storing the application's 'truth' in its presentation layer seems illogical and often invites bad code. Whenever I see a node with a bunch of `data-` attributes, and a query to those attributes it feels like a design problem - just use an object. Also, it's _my_ document with things I created, except for the static HTML case, why should I query it?

Comment: Err... XSS only matters when it affects *another user's* page, are you aware of that?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes, but also - global mutable shared state and name collisions ;)

Comment: @blender There isn't really a user input. The user just gets a script tag which is a widget and they can place it on their website which other people can click and start chatting with them. But since the user copies and paste the code on their website, they could always modify or play around with the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends.

An attacker can modify anything he wants in his browser, so it doesn't matter how much sanitization you put in the front-end, an attacker can work his way around all your javascript functions and the like to circumvent your front-end code.

I'm not saying that you shouldn't sanitize your input in the front-end because it will always help in terms of usability and experience for a legitimate user.

If the address that you're redirecting your user to uses that data attribute to do something with the server, then yes by all means sanitize it in both places: front and back end. Otherwise, you shouldn't worry, the worst case scenario is that a malicious user (or a knowledgable one) will end up in a 404 page.

** EDIT **

After reading your comment in this answer, here's my updated answer:

The dangers reside in how you're using that piece of information. Take as an example google analytics script:

Google provides with you a script that will help you track your visitors actions and behaviors through google analytics interface.

If you change any value in google's script, google analytics won't work, and there's no way you can hack google through the analytics script.

How does google achieve this? They put all their security in the backend, and they sanitize modifiable user input that will be rendered in a website, stored in a database or somehow interacts with the server.

Back to your case:

If you're going to use that data attribute to do a document.write(), an `eval`, do a database lookup or any sensitive operation (delete, update, retrieve data) then yes by all means: sanitize it.

How are you going to sanitize it? That's problem specific and more than likely you should ask a new question.

Comment: @AlanChavez Thanks for your answer Alan. Basically what is happening is that I'm giving each user a script like the facebook like script to paste on their website so that when a user clicks on that widget they will start a chat with the user hosted by my website. But since the user has to copy the script from my website and paste on theirs, they could always play around with the values on the way. So I was wondering about the dangers that could occur.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is taken from user input or generated from user input, yes, you should definitely perform sanitation. However, if you're asking if data attributes are somehow vulnerable in a way other attributes aren't, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

A user with access to the browser (e.g. via XSS) can insert anything into a data attribute. But (s)he can just redirect anywhere at anytime, so this trivial case is irrelevant.

If the value is set by a user via some other means, then the link could be set somewhere other than intended within the same domain. That might be *annoying* but it shouldn't be a security risk.

If you're doing something else, like including a javascript string for `eval` in the attribute and that comes from a user (e.g. via a database value), then you will create an XSS vulnerability. But you should never, ever, ever, trust user supplied values anyway. Nothing special about html data attributes there.

Comment: Yeah exactly that's what I was thinking. I wasn't really seeing any more danger than being redirected to another url which was't intended.

Answer (score 0):

> > Do you need to sanitize the value before using it for a redirect?

No need to sanitize ***before***, but you need to sanitize ***after***.

In your example, if you are not sanitizing data - you can get a victim of classic XSS.

I.e: `http://www.example.com/ + value`, where value is `search?q=<script>alert(1)</script>`, and where search page actually outputs raw query to the browser.

p.s.: this is not specific to data-attributes. It will work the same with normal attributes.

Comment: That's a lot of assumptions for something that the OP didn't explicitly write.